# Chrome or Firefox extension to reload a page till it actually loads (I'm getting the error: The connection has timed out)

Tags: chrome, firefox, browser-extension

I'm in one of those Government websites that are down quite often, so I must reload the page over and over expecting that it will load in some moment.

I wonder if there is some kind of extension that not only loads the page each certain period of time, but **ALSO STOP RELOADING ONCE IT ACTUALLY LOADS**.

Or maybe some other solution to fix the problem?

[image: screenshot The connection has timed out)]

Comment: What do you mean by "stop realoading once it actually loads"? The bolding and caps lock on this part is very confusing and I assume completely unnecessary, if you just mean that the extension should notice that the website loaded and it shouldn't refresh anymore, which is kind of obvious.

Comment: @Destroy666 exactly: "the extension should notice that the website loaded and it shouldn't refresh anymore". As far as I understood, all extensions I saw reload the page according the interval set no matter what.